# No Module Exported in Angular/core

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to do animation in my angular 2 small app, but while importing the some style, animate, trigger module I'm getting error node_module angular/core does not have exported module trigger, style etc.

sample code of my component,

```
import { 
    Component,
    OnInit,
    Input,
    trigger,
    state,
    style,
    animate,
    transition } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: have you installed the node plugins?

Comment: Check the path, should be `node_modules\@angular\core`

Comment: yes, I have done the npm install and I have all node module, and yes the path is same as node_modle\@angular\core. Still I'm getting the error